permission denied error while trying to copy file from my desktop to a ec2 instance using scp command
I am trying to copy a file from my windows machine to ec2 instance. I am using following command to do so.
scp -i "C:\Users\abc\AWSServer\MyEc.pem" "C:\Users\ABC\Mypython.py" ec2-user@_._.__.__:/home/ec2-user/PythonProgram

I am getting the permission denied error like follows:
scp: dest open "/home/ec2-user/PythonProgram/Mypython.py": Permission denied
scp: failed to upload file C:/Users/ABC/Mypython.py to /home/ec2-user/PythonProgram

does anybody knows the solution.

Okay i got the answer. i changed the permission to the directory using chmod command
sudo chmod a+w /home/ec2-user/PythonProgram

